# uncaught PHP exception causing 500 server error

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

In a newly installed MAMP, an uncaught PHP exception is causing an HTTP 500 server error, instead of being trapped by PHP. For example, this program causes a 500:

```
<?php throw new Exception(); ?>
```

That's the whole file -- no calls to set_error_handler, or anything else. On my other machine, I have XDebug installed, and uncaught exceptions produce an XDebug message, so the two situations aren't directly comparable.

Everything I've read online says that uncaught exceptions result in a fatal error *from PHP*, and that's the behavior I recall seeing prior to installing XDebug on that other machine.

Ideas?

(Please don't tell me to catch the exception. I'm trying to investigate what happens with uncaught exceptions. My question is about them.)

Comment: They cause a 500 error with display errors turned off

Comment: Also it will generally write to the web servers error log.

Comment: Thanks! I had set them On, but perhaps with the server running. Restarting it put php.ini back where it was. I think this is a result of how MAMP manages multiple PHP versions. Why not post this an an answer so I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically a server will cause a server error (500) and drop an entry in the server's error log.you can change this behavior by setting display errors on in the INI

Comment: just a side note, the error log will be writed still if you turn display_errors on

Comment: and another one - the `display_errors` can be change during runtime for the specific run with `ini_set` : `ini_set("display_errors",true);`

Comment: @YaronU. You just saved me hours of headache. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

go to your php.ini file and find the following lines

```
display_errors = Off

display_startup_errors = Off
```

and set both to on

also seting

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

could help to debug

dont forget to save and restart the webserver service (it migth be iss or httpd (in caseyou are using apache))

Comment: "restart the server", should be more specific, i.e. "restart httpd (or iis) (service)"

Comment: I had done that. Problem is that with MAMP, editing php.ini with Apache running is ineffective, even if you then restart. I totally forgot to check display_errors with phpinfo().